# How to create a Procedure with a specific WITH clause in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, plsql

I have a problem by creating a Procdure with a specific WITH clause. I use an Oracle database. I need a temp table for mapping specific values during time of execution.

In addition I have the following Oracle procedure. This Procedure will be created and executed by bringing into database:

How can I create this kind of Oracle SQL Procedure? Many thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your WITH clause in a cursor FOR loop in your procedure:

```
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE myProcedure(pinSchema IN VARCHAR2) AS
  BEGIN
    FOR aRow IN (WITH t AS (SELECT 'myFirstOldSchema'  AS OLD_SCHEMA,
                                   'myFirstNewSchema'  AS NEW_SCHEMA
                              FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                            SELECT 'mySecondOldSchema' AS OLD_SCHEMA,
                                   'mySecondNewSchema' AS NEW_SCHEMA
                              FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                            SELECT 'myThirdOldSchema'  AS OLD_SCHEMA,
                                   'myThirdNewSchema'  AS NEW_SCHEMA
                              FROM DUAL)
                  SELECT t.*
                   FROM t
                   WHERE t.OLD_SCHEMA = pinSchema)
    LOOP
      -- Here a specific value from column "OLD_SCHEMA" must be inserted  

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || aRow.OLD_SCHEMA ||
                          '.myTable(column_1, column_2, column_3)
                           (SELECT extern_column_1,
                                   extern_column_2,
                                   extern_column_3
                             FROM ' || aRow.NEW_SCHEMA || '.myExternTable)';
    END LOOP;
  END myProcedure;

BEGIN
  FOR S IN (SELECT * FROM ROOT_SCHEMA.myTableWithSchema)
  LOOP        
    -- First  loop S.mySchemata represent the value 'myFirstOldSchema'
    -- Second loop S.mySchemata represent the value 'mySecondOldSchema'
    -- Third  loop S.mySchemata represent the value 'myThirdOldSchema'
    myProcedure(S.mySchemata);
  END LOOP

  COMMIT;    
END;
```

Not tested on animals - you'll be first!